# Make colspan(ed) and rowspan(ed) table cell contents occupy full height

Tags: html, cell, css-tables

First of all, pardon me for bringing up this hugely discussed issue once more through this question.

My site has a Dashboard (similar to iGoogle) and an option for the user to switch between different layout options for the Dashboard. A couple of these layouts have *table cells* spanning more than a *row* and/or *column* `(rowspan and colspan)`. At such *cells* the **`<div>`** within does not occupy the *100% height* available inside **`<td>`** when the browser window is re-sized to a small view - around 800x570. My current resolution is 1280x1024.

The layout is like this: [image: Problematic layout]

Some style information:
**body** height: 100%;
**table** cellspacing: 0; cellpadding: 0; border-spacing: 2px; margin: 0; padding: 0;
**th, tr, td** vertical-align: top;

I have read and applied solutions of these posts, but to no avail.
[Full height div inside td](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828442/full-height-div-inside-td)
[DIV stretch to height 100% in a table cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/589754/div-stretch-to-height-100-in-a-table-cell)
[Getting div to occupy full cell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737584/getting-div-to-occupy-full-cell-height)
[How to make <div> fill <td> height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542090/how-to-make-div-fill-td-height)

Please help!

Comment: create a jsfiddle or paste complete code here including html

Comment: Its more than 3000 lines of code including HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I am trying to downsize it to the problem points only. Need more time.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble: I found the problem while downsizing the html for you. The issue was with the content of the smaller cells of the first row. When the browser was re-sized to a small size, the `div` contents of these small td's would stack above one another (originally, side-by-side), thus increasing the total height requirement of the cell as compared to the other three large cells. I have worked around this by ensuring a minimum width of 990px for this layout and 1160px for the body `(min-width:)`. Hope that is not a wrong way of doing it. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the content of the smaller **cells** of the *first row*. When the browser was re-sized to a small size, the **div** contents of these small **td's** would stack above one another (originally, side-by-side), thus increasing the total *height* requirement of the **cell** as compared to the other three large **cells**. I have worked around this by ensuring a minimum width of *990px* for this layout and *1160px* for the **body** `(min-width:)`